# Unable to start apache webserver due to ld.so.1: httpd: libonssys.so: open failed

Tags: apache, shared-libraries, httpd.conf, profile, nosuchfileexception

When I do the below I'm able to start and stop apache instance alright

```
$ sudo -u wsadm -I -H
$ cd /web/apps/perf/apache/2.4.41/https-harsh/bin
$ ./apachectl -k start
```

However, when I ssh directly to the destination host using wsadm user and try to start the instance I get the below error:

```
$ ./apachectl -k start 

httpd: Syntax error on line 531 of /web/apps/perf/apache/2.4.41/https-harsh/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load /web/apps/perf/apache/2.4.41/https-harsh/plugin_lib/lib/mod_wl_24.so into server: ld.so.1: httpd: libonssys.so: open failed: No such file or directory
```

I was suggested to source the profile so I did the below:

1. `. /home/wsadm/.profile
2. `source /home/wsadm/.profile`

However, I still get the same error starting apache webserver instance.

```
cat /home/wsadm/.profile
…..
.….
WLS_PLUGIN_HOME=/web/apps/perf/sjsws/webserver7/wlsplugins/wlsplugin-1.1
LD_LIBRARY_PATH_64=${WLS_PLUGIN_HOME}/lib:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH_64}
export WLS_PLUGIN_HOME LD_LIBRARY_PATH LD_LIBRARY_PATH_64
…..
```

As you can see the .profile does not even have apache folder mentioned for any of the variables or paths. Sorry, if I'm taking the thought process in the wrong direction by mentioning the contents of the .profile

Can you please suggest ?